# simple html dom not working correctly

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
<?php
    include("includes/simple_html_dom.php") ;

    $url_to_get = "http://getconfused.net/" ;
    $homePage = file_get_html($url_to_get);
    $allLinks = $homePage->find('a');
    foreach ( $allLinks as $link)
    {
         $href = $link->innertext ;
         echo $href . "</br>" ;
    }
?>
```

Simple. Just fetch a page, find any links and print the innertext(`<a >innertext</a>`) . But for some reason simple html dom here is skipping a lot of links. TO be specific, its missing all the links from the first div (`<div id="getconfused">`) of the page.
Why ? what can one do to remedy the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is that div in the body? And is the page otherwise valid? 
Probably the html is corrupt in that part, causing the div to be skipped.

Comment: And is the HTML valid? Maybe you can use a validator to check that. The fact that the links are shown in a browser doesn't mean the HTML is valid. An error might be implicitly corrected by the browser while simple_html_dom might not be able to parse the error.